# Facebook Login + Rest API

Tags: rest, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am building a SPA (Single-page application) that is going to consume and REST API. My application will use the facebook login.

Just to clarify my ideas:

1. I will use Facebook SDK (javascript) to authenticate my new user. Facebook will give me an access token. This will run on client side.
2. Now,  i will make a request to my REST API. Do i need to pass the access token to the REST API? DO i need to verify always to see if the user is logged?

I know it is a newbie question..

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using the JavaScript SDK (and [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.1)), you don´t need to worry about the Access Token - at least not in most cases.

You can verify if a user is authorized already by using [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) on page load.